# Simple moduleloader doesnt work

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I'm doing some basic tests with the moduleloader in flex, but i cant get it to work.

What i'm doing is the following:
in my main .mxml file i added the following inside a canvas:

```
<mx:ModuleLoader id="tagModuleLoader" error="tagModuleLoader_errorHandler(event)" url="com/test/vincent/modules/ImageFramesModule.swf"/>
```

And in my module i have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" initialize="module1_initializeHandler(event)" layout="absolute" width="400" height="300">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function module1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                trace("inside the module");
            }   
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Label x="163" y="139" text="image frames"/>
</mx:Module>
```

When i run the project i allways get the following error:

```
Error #2035: URL niet gevonden. URL: app:/Library/WebServer/testProject/bin-debug/com/test/vincent/modules/ImageFramesModule.swf
```

The module is swf file is present at that location but it still tells me that it cant be found
I do have to mention that if i run the module swf, i only get a blank blue screen, even if i add a panel or a label or whatever. I also have to mention that i'm not using the default "flex 4.5" sdk but the "extension builder 3.4" sdk.

Can anyone tell me why my swf files arent found?

Comment: nah, allready tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your framework, its a bug that was patched.  ;)